# Git Interactive Rebase Patch Before a 3-Way Merge

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following Git history:

[image: Git History Before]

I would like to interactive rebase from commit `1f63` (2 commits prior) to HEAD at `feature/project-setup` as follows:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

The `git-rebase-todo` file then has the following lines:

```
pick ff7abc8 Install initial project site packages
pick 1696181 Add `.bumpversion.cfg`
```

If I change the first line to `edit`, apply my changes, then do a `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue`, my commit history now looks like this:

[image: Git History After]

I understand interactive git rebase is cherry-picking the two commits onto the root of the rebase (in this case, commit `1f63`). My question is, how can I overwrite `1696` with `e16f` and have the branching stay the same? (I want my final history to look like the original, but `1696` will be replaced by the new commit `e16f` that has my changes)

My initial thought is I might first need to cherry pick those commits, then delete them, add a break, checkout `feature/project-setup` and then do a fast-forward merge commit. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** If there's a simpler way to do this that doesn't require resetting develop, master, and `0cea8` and then remerging, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `the simple linear history of the original patch`? Like, you would like c598 to have 646f as a parent instead of 1696, for example?

Comment: @eftshift0 Bad re-use of terminology on my end, but yes that's what I mean. I want `1696` and `ff7a` to go away and `64c6` and `e16f` to take their places, respectively.

Comment: @eftshift0 I edited the wording of my question, in case that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE: 06-MAY-2021

Here is a (relatively) simple bash script that will update branch names and tags. **USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!** Place this either in

```
/usr/bin/  # On Linux
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin  # On Windows
```

and name it

```
git-rebase-bti
```

(without a file extension), and make it executable

```
chmod +x path/to/git-rebase-bti
```

or on Windows

```
icacls path/to/git-rebase-bti /grant your_usrnm:(rx)
```

though I believe Windows gives executable permissions for files by default? (Don't quote me on that)

```
#! /bin/sh -
#
# Git Rebase Branch Names, Tags, and Forks
#
# File:
#   git-rebase-bti
#
# Installation Instructions:
#   Place this file in the following folder:
#     - Linux: `/usr/bin/`
#     - Windows: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`
#
# Usage:
#   git rebase-bti <SHA> 
#
# Authors:
# Copyleft 2020 Adam Hendry. All rights reserved.
#
# Original Author:
# Copyleft 2020 Adam Hendry. All rights reserved.
#
# License:
# GNU GPL vers. 2.0
# 
# This script is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this script; if not, write to the
# Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
# Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

GIT_DIR='.git'
REBASE_DIR="${GIT_DIR}/rebase-merge"
TODO_FILE="${REBASE_DIR}/git-rebase-todo"
TODO_BACKUP="${TODO_FILE}.backup"

HEADS_FOLDER='refs/heads'
TAGS_FOLDER='refs/tags'
REWRITTEN_FOLDER='refs/rewritten'

# Initialize associative array (dictionary) variables
declare -A labels_by_sha  # Rebase label names indexed by original SHA
declare -A shas_by_label  # Original SHAs indexed by rebase label names

# Get heads (remove '.git/refs/heads' from beginning)
heads=($(find "${GIT_DIR}/${HEADS_FOLDER}" -type f | cut -d '/' -f 4-))

# Get tags (remove '.git/refs/tags' from beginning)
tags=($(find "${GIT_DIR}/${TAGS_FOLDER}" -type f | cut -d '/' -f 4-))

# Start the rebase operation in the background
git rebase -i --rebase-merges $1 &

# Capture the process ID
pid_main=$!

# Wait until the todo file is created
until [ -e "$TODO_FILE" ] && [ -e "$TODO_BACKUP" ]
do
  continue
done

# Store rebase message
rebase_message=$(tac $TODO_FILE | sed '/^$/q' | tac)

# Store todo list
rebase_message_length=$(echo "$rebase_message" | wc -l)
todo_list=$(cat $TODO_FILE | head -n -"$rebase_message_length")

# Prompt user
printf "Calculating todo file. Please wait..." > $TODO_FILE

# Get label names
label_names=($(grep -oP '^(l|label) \K[^ ]*$' -- $TODO_BACKUP))

for label_name in "${label_names[@]}"
do
  if [ $label_name = 'onto' ]
  then
    continue
  fi
  
  command_line=$(grep -B 1 -P '^(l|label) '"$label_name"'$' $TODO_BACKUP | head -n 1 | sed 's/\n//g')
  command_name=$(echo "$command_line" | grep -oP '^(p|pick|m|merge)(?= )')
  
  label_sha=
  
  if [ "$command_name" = 'p' ] || [ "$command_name" = 'pick' ]
  then
    label_sha=$(echo $command_line | grep -oP '^(p|pick) \K[[:alnum:]]*' | cut -c1-7)
  elif [ "$command_name" = 'm' ] || [ "$command_name" = 'merge' ]
  then
    label_sha=$(echo $command_line | grep -oP '^(m|merge) -[cC] \K[[:alnum:]]*' | cut -c1-7)
  fi
  
  shas_by_label["$label_name"]="$label_sha"
  labels_by_sha["$label_sha"]="$label_name"
done

# Restore Branch Names
todo_list+="\n\n# Restore Branch Names\n"

for head in "${heads[@]}"
do
  sha=$(cat "${GIT_DIR}/${HEADS_FOLDER}/${head}" | cut -c1-7)
  
  if [ -n "${labels_by_sha[$sha]}" ]
  then
    todo_list+='exec git update-ref '"${HEADS_FOLDER}/${head}"' '"${REWRITTEN_FOLDER}/${labels_by_sha[$sha]}\n"
  fi
  
  # elif in `git rev-list`, pick sha and label it, then `git update-ref` here`
  
done

todo_list+='\n# Restore Tag Names\n'

for tag in "${tags[@]}"
do
  sha=$(cat "${GIT_DIR}/${TAGS_FOLDER}/${tag}" | cut -c1-7)
  
  if [ -n "${labels_by_sha[$sha]}" ]
  then
    todo_list+='exec git update-ref '"${TAGS_FOLDER}/${tag}"' '"${REWRITTEN_FOLDER}/${labels_by_sha[$sha]}\n"
  fi
done

todo_list+="$rebase_message"

# Update todo file
printf "$todo_list" > $TODO_FILE

# Wait until the rebase operation is completed
wait $pid_main

# Exit the script
exit 0
```

---

### Answer:

Interactive rebasing can be used to effect these changes, but the branch and tag names that exist between `HEAD` and the root of the rebase, which would otherwise prevent Git's garbage collection from removing these older commits, must first be removed and then reapplied after the rebasing. Unfortunately, to work properly, rebasing must be started from the tip of your history (i.e. the `develop` branch)

Rebase from `develop`:

```
git checkout develop
git branch -D feature/project-setup
git branch -D master
git tag -d 0.1.0
git rebase -i --rebase-merges
```

Add the `edit` to the commit you wish to change, then stage the changes (`git add -A`), amend commit (`git commit --amend`), and finish rebasing (`git rebase --continue`).

Afterwards, add the branch and tag names back one-by-one

```
git branch master cfa8
git branch feature/project-setup 1696
git checkout master
git tag 0.1.0
```

Although the git-rebasetags script developed [here](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/08/14/rebasing-in-git-without-losing-tags/) is a good start, it only works on Linux machines, only rebases tags and not branch names, matches on tag commit messages (which won't work for non-annotated tags), and uses python instead of shell scripting, which is slightly less portable.

Alternatively, the `rebase-todo` could be updated as follows:

```
label onto

# Branch feature-project-setup
reset onto
pick ff7abc83 Install initial project site packages
pick 1696181f Add `.bumpversion.cfg`
label feature-project-setup

# Branch release-0-1-0
reset 8e2d63e # Initial commit
merge -C c598c3bf feature-project-setup # Merge branch 'feature/project-setup' into develop
label branch-point
pick 0cea85a3 Bump version: 0.0.0 → 0.1.0
label release-0-1-0

# Branch 0-1-0
reset 8e2d63e # Initial commit
merge -C cfa8ed17 release-0-1-0 # Merge branch 'release/0.1.0' into master
label 0-1-0

reset branch-point # Merge branch 'feature/project-setup' into develop
merge -C a22db135 0-1-0 # Merge tag '0.1.0' into develop
label develop

# Reset branch and tag names
reset feature-project-setup
exec git branch -D feature/project-setup
exec git branch feature/project-setup

reset 0-1-0
exec git tag -d 0.1.0
exec git tag 0.1.0
exec git branch -D master
exec git branch master
reset develop
```

Or, since git rebase writes labels to `refs/rewritten`, this could be done in fewer lines with some plumbing commands:

```
exec git update-ref refs/heads/feature/project-setup refs/rewritten/feature-project-setup
exec git update-ref refs/heads/master refs/rewritten/0-1-0
exec git update-ref refs/tags/0.1.0 refs/rewritten/0-1-0
```

where in the above the label `0-1-0` applies to both `master` and tag `0.1.0` in this particular instance.

It would be great if this could be made into extra options for rebase, like `--rebase-tags` and `rebase-branch-names`. Unfortunately, a `pre-rebase` hook won't work because this happens before the `rebase-todo` is made. Also, there is no `post-rebase` hook. So, it seems a separate shell script would be prudent.

Lastly, the above doesn't rebase fork points, which would also be needed if there's an unmerged fork point in the rebase path revision list. If that happens, you can try adding the following at the end of your todo list:

```
reset new_base_branch  # Be sure to `label new_base_branch` before here at right spot
exec git branch temp_name  # Give new base a temp name
exec git checkout branch_to_rebase
exec git rebase temp_name
exec git branch -D temp_name
```

This would also be a great additional option (like `--rebase-forks`), but the code would also need to check that `branch_to_rebase` doesn't actually have a child that merges back into the `onto` branch outside the rebase path. For best safety, I would always `rebase -i --rebase-merges` from the tip commit of your repository.

Answer (score 1):

> If there's a simpler way to do this that doesn't require resetting develop, master, and `0cea8` and then remerging, please let me know.

There isn't, but the notion of resetting `0cea8` is nonsense as well.  One can only "reset" branch names (well, and Git's index, and your working tree, because Git jammed too many things into the `git reset` command).  See the One Big Thing to know about branch names below.

There are several things to realize about commits:

- They are completely, totally read-only.
- Their *true* name is their hash ID, which is computed from the content of the commit (including the metadata—technically it's computed solely from metadata since the saved snapshot is metadata).
- The metadata of any one given commit gives the raw hash ID of its predecessor commit (if it's a regular single-parent commit), or of all of its parents (if it is a merge commit).

These, put together, mean that you can always *copy* a commit to a new and improved version, but having done so, you must now copy every "downstream" (subsequent) commit.  That's because, given something like:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the "last" commit in the sequence, if we've copied `F` to a new and improved `F'`, we'll need a new-and-improved `G` where the improvement, or at least one of them, is that the parent of `G'` is `F'`.  Then we will also need to copy `H` to a new and improved `H'` so that its parent can be `G'`.

There's really just one big thing to know about *branch names* like `master` and `develop`—almost everything else flows from this one big thing—and that is that each one just holds *one* commit hash ID.  Whatever hash ID is stored in the branch name, that commit is the *last* commit of that branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

The *last* commit of branch `branch` is commit `H`.  It's commit `H` itself that causes commit `G` to be part of branch `branch`, and then it's commit `G` itself that causes commit `F` to be part of the branch, and so on, backwards through history.  The history *is* the set of commits: no more and no less.

So, if you have some history you don't like, you can build new history—new commits—that you do like, but having made even a single-bit change to some *past* commit, the new-and-improved commit has a different hash ID, and this change ripples down through the rest of the commits.

Git 2.18 learned a new `--rebase-merges` option that lets you reconstruct certain histories by not only automatically copying individual commits, but also repeating merge operations (merge commits cannot be *copied* so the merges must be re-performed instead).  This gets you most of the way, but still requires manual adjustment of branch names, so that the point to the new-and-improved commits.

Comment: Thank you again for your collaboration, but again, exclamatory remarks are uncessary. You can `git reset` to any SHA, so it is not nonsense. Furthermore, in very rare circumstances, actions such as `git replace` coupled with `git filter-branch -- --all` can be used to effect rewrites where the SHA's are more-or-less overwritten. Albeit, this usage is not highly recommended and git even recommends using the tool `git filter-repo` for such large file rewrites.

Comment: That being said, I do believe you are right that `--rebase-merges` can be used, but you are right that tags and branch names that would otherwise cause git's garbage collection to fail must first be removed and then manually re-enetered after the rebasing.

Comment: Sure, you can reset *to* `0cea8`, but you can't reset `0cea8` itself. Maybe that was just a typo? I can't see any sensible interpretation of it though.